# How do I find out why my mobile version isn't shrinking to fit the screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/), I have the `viewport` meta tag,

```
%meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no", :name => "viewport"}/
```

and I've hidden all my images with `.hidden-xs-up`. Yet still it displays about 25% too big in the Chrome mobile display. How can I debug this to find out which element is using up all the width?

Comment: Part of the problem is Chrome. I used a real iPhone and it looks so different. Chrome is just too unreliable. I might have to switch back to Opera. Just turning off mobile, reload, scroll, turn on mobile, reload again can drastically change the look, and sometimes it will fit and look correct.

Comment: I commented out vast swaths of the HAML with `-#` until it looked OK on a real phone, then narrowed it down from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this to debug.

With your page open in Chrome, open web inspector. Then in the Elements pane, hover over the different elements on your page and look for one which is too wide and extends outside the viewport.

Once you've located the problem, inspect its CSS. Sometimes the cause of the problem may actually be with an element's parent or child. So if you find a div which is too wide but its CSS looks OK, inspect the CSS for other elements which are close by.

Good luck!

Comment: They are nearly all too wide, to fit the space available, like `<p class="display-4">Benefits of membership</p>`. That should not be a problem but it extends beyond the screen because of something else that I can't find.

Comment: Can you post the URL @Chloe?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Chloe . In the second half of your page you have 3 images, each inside col-6 divs. These images aren't scaling and this is breaking your grid. To ensure these images scale at smaller viewports, add the class="img-fluid" to each of these. See https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `width: 100%;` to your wrapper?

Maybe try `box-sizing: border-box;` on padded elements

Comment: Adding `width: 100%` to `.container` in Chrome didn't help - didn't change the display.